# Генерация текста на картинке, но не капча

Tags: php

Приветствую

Прошу дать совет, а лучше код, по **нестандартному** вопросу (решение в стиле мсье)

Можно ли как то сгенерить на PHP изображение (jpg), на нем, как на html странице написать определенный текст.. вы сразу подумаете капча! не.., хотя близко

```
//просто манипуляции с текстом
<div style="font-size:16px; font-weight:700; color:#999999;">
   qweretruy<br>hsdfsdg
</div>
gsdfbsd<br>fgsdfg
```

р.s. да, если копать в тему капчи создать изображение это уже не проблема, но то, что там генериться это не чистый текст, а каракозябры для спам ботом

Comment: > Можно ли как то сгенерить на PHP изображение (jpg)

да, посмотрите документацию по [gd](http://www.php.net//manual/ru/book.image.php) (стоит на каждом серваке) и [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php) (стоит не везде, но лично мне сним удобнее работать). Конкретно в данной задаче вам нужно создать изображение (imagecreatetruecolor()), заполнить его (imagettftext()) и сохранить (imagejpeg()).

Comment: @Fike, что ж не в ответах? я тут для себя целый мир открыл )

Comment: @mixalef, пушо нормальный ответ - это цельный пример кода с полным теоретическим обоснованием, а не пара ссылок :3

Comment: Я поклонник freebsd. А там если спрашиваеш как сделать медную статую, то ответ один - вот тебе кирка, медная шахта в той стороне. Читая документацию, а не используя готовый код, быстрее учатся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение раз - [GD2](http://php.net//manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php)
Решение два - [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagickdraw.annotation.php)